# What is the importance of bull in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, gods, identification-request, animals

We all know about cow's importance in Vedas. If cow is called the mother then bull is the father.

So **what are some Vedic verses which glorify the bull?**

Even the Mahabharata gives importance to bull by saying "bull among men" etc
And, the Vedas too call Gods like Agni as **bull**.

Answer (score 2):

what are some Vedic verses which glorify the bull?

In  [**AtharvaVeda**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/atharveda/v1.118)  Kanda 4 -Sukta -11
Anagvaan Sukta. **Supreme Brahman ( Ishwara) is symbolically called as bull ,who carries the  cart load of this universe.**

> अङ्गवान दाधार पृथिवीमु द्यामनडवान दाधारोर्वSन्तरिक्षम् ।
>  अङ्गवान्
>   दाधार प्रदिश: षडूर्विरङ्गवान विश्वं भुवनमा विवेश ।।1।।
>
> Prithivi (earth) is held by Ishwara ,who is pulling a cart of this
>   universe and **who is in the form of bull**. He also holding Swarga Loka
>   (Heaven), Antariksha (Space) as well as all the six directions like
>   east etc. In this way this way this Anagvaan (puller of cart) ishwara
>   is incusive in all the worlds (Universe).

Here Ishwara( Brahman) is said to be a bull who is pulling cart of universe. Here he is compared with bull , who is having  power to pull cart of load.

---

[image]

Comment: hello @swiftpushkar **excellent** answer but i am expecting a detailed answer means as gods which are related to bull as above i mentioned god agni and few more verses as it should be little detailed. you don't need to add hindi text it's ok

Comment: @Fiercelord - Yes , I know , but just given answer with what I found , I will try provide the detail answer and i am searching still .But unfortunately this is just for what I found for time being.

Comment: Its okay @ SwiftPushkar

Comment: This not answering the Q. OP is asking just like there are Vedic mantras that praise the Cow are there similar mantras for the bull? Your answer says Iswara is compared to Bull but Op wants to see where Bull is compared to some Gods etc.